# Return Observable<number> from another observable with a computation over a Observable<[]>

Tags: angular, observable, angular-promise

I am trying to return an Observable on a single number from another observable on an array. I use the array to look up two values and do a computation. Currently I am using a Promise which is fine but for my own understanding I would like to know how it is done.

How do I convert the following code that returns a Promise

```
convertToCurrency(fromCurrency: string, toCurrency: string) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          this.getQuotes()
            .subscribe(quotes =>  {

              let usdFrom = quotes.filter(val => {
                return val.code.substring(3, 6) == fromCurrency;
              })[0].quote;

              let usdTo = quotes.filter(val => {
                return val.code.substring(3, 6) == toCurrency;
              })[0].quote;

              let converted = usdTo / usdFrom;

              resolve(converted);

            }, error => reject());

        });

      }
```

into this:

```
convertToCurrency(fromCurrency: string, toCurrency: string): Observable<number> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost the same as your were already doing with a promise.

```
convertToCurrency(fromCurrency: string, toCurrency: string): Observable<number> {

        return new Observable<number>(observer => {

          this.getQuotes()
            .subscribe(quotes =>  {

              let usdFrom = quotes.filter(val => {
                return val.code.substring(3, 6) == fromCurrency;
              })[0].quote;

              let usdTo = quotes.filter(val => {
                return val.code.substring(3, 6) == toCurrency;
              })[0].quote;

              let converted = usdTo / usdFrom;

              observer.next(converted);

            }, error => observer.error(error));

        });

      }
```